# Python: Boto3, specifying attribute names for delete_item operation

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

The following code gives me an error:

```py
dynamo_table.delete_item(Key={'segmentUuid': segment_id, 'value': value})
```

Error:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DeleteItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema

After doing some searching, I found that the issue is due to the sort key column being called `value` which is a reserved keyword in Dynamo. 
Unfortunately, boto3 doesn't seem to allow me to specify that using ExpressionAttributeName argument since it's unsupported for Key in `delete_item` operation. Can someone please suggest what I could do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`value` being a reserved word does make it confusing, but that error should have been

```
"Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: value"
```

in that case.

Your error occurs when you are trying to match an item by fields which are not hash/sort keys. So for this particular `delete_item` to work, you need a [GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) with

segmentUuid → hash key

value → sort key